# Input must be 15 characters long

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I want to display a message if the user fail to add the correct number of characters to the input field with id of addchipnumber. Minimum length is 15 and maximum is 15. 
I have not yet gotten this to work.... I seems like it shouldn't be that difficult to do.

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Lägg till/ändra ID-nummer</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="addchipnumber">Chipnummer</label>
        <input type="text" id="addchipnumber" class="form-control" ng-model="data.idNumber" mask="999999999999999" restrict="reject" required >
        <p><small>Chipnummer består av 15 siffror.</small></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="addtattoonumber">Tatueringsnummer</label>
        <input type="text" id="addtattoonumber" class="form-control" ng-model="data.tattooNumber">
        <p><small>Tatueringsnummer består av maximalt 6 tecken</small></p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer" style="text-align: center">
    <button class="btn btn-back text-center" type="button" ng-click="cancel()"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Avbryt</button>
    <button class="btn btn-green text-center" type="button" ng-click="ok()"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> SPARA </button>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post your js?

Answer (score 1):

What you are searching for is `ngMessages` with form validation.

```
<form name="myForm">
    <label>
        <input type="text" name="textEntry" ng-model="Chipnummer" ng-minlength="15" ng-maxlength="15" required/>
    </label>

    <div ng-messages="myForm.textEntry.$error" style="color:red">
        <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
        <div ng-message="minlength">Input length must be 15 chars</div>
        <div ng-message="maxlength">Input length must be 15 chars</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/zhHth7ddOIiHLQoxKt4o?p=preview)**

In this case, `ng-message` *"minlength"* will appear if input length is less than `ngMinlength` value (15). Same for *"maxlength"*.

Required is for a mandatory field.